# Auto increase cell reference based on sheet name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 1 master sheet with a lot of data that I want to divide to several sheet.

for example :

> in sheet 1 the formula in cell A3 is =mastersheet!B4 and
>
> in sheet 2 the formula in cell A3 is =mastersheet!B5.

the adding number is using the sheet name, so if I using 3 as the sheet name it would be =mastersheet!B(4+3).

Can anyone help me with the formula?

Comment: "the adding number is using the sheet name" ??? could you please post a bit more sample data to help us understand your situation?

Comment: I'm planning to use 1, 2, 3 an so on as the sheet name.

Comment: sample data means screenshot, not plain numbers with almost no context.

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand your problem, but you get the sheet number from =sheet(), maybe this helps? Something like =mastersheet!B(sheet()+3) or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple VBA macro to setup formulas in sheets *Sheet1, Sheet2,* and *Sheet3*:

```
Sub FormulaSetup()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, increasing As Long

    For Each sh In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
        increasing = CLng(Mid(sh.Name, 6) + 3)
        sh.Range("A3").Formula = "=mastersheet!B" & increasing
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Just modify the `Array()` statement to include all the sheets you want to modify.

The result *(in Sheet3)*:

[image]